# Apache Cassandra 3.11.x Cloning Keyspaces

Tags: cassandra

We are working with Apache Cassandra 3.11 and we are trying to prepare for a DR situation. For instance, we have two keyspaces that we back up via snapshot. For instance, via Ansible:

```
- name: Create snapshots
  shell: "nodetool snapshot --tag {{ item.tag }} {{ item.name }}"
  loop: "{{ keyspaces }}"
```

Now If we had to create a new cluster and use these snapshots, from what we understand, we would need to do the following:

- Create new cluster (3)
- Create keyspaces
- Restore each table via the snapshot `schema.cql`
- Use sstableloader

per node (only 2, third node has no snapshot), then

- Nodetool repair

per node

A reference to this path can be found [here](https://docs.rackspace.com/blog/apache-casandra-backup-and-recovery/)

However, the tables are loaded, but the data is duplicated, in our case, as we only have two nodes with snapshots as the third has none (failed node).

Are we following the correct path here? We have tried copying the snapshot data to the appropriate directory and used `nodetool refresh -- keyspace table` but the data never appeared.

Any ideas/help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I refer to this operation as **cloning keyspaces or tables**. To me the term "restore" is ambiguous because it can mean recovering the data to the same nodes as where the backup was taken.

You can only use the `refresh` method if you're recovering the snapshots to a destination cluster that is identical in configuration to the source cluster. By "identical configuration", I mean:

- the cluster topologies are identical -- same number of DCs, same number of nodes in each DC
- the token assignments are identical -- the assigned tokens for each node in one cluster is a mirror-image of the nodes in another cluster

If the clusters are identical, follow the steps I documented in this post -- https://community.datastax.com/questions/4534/.

For non-identical clusters, follow the steps I documented in this post -- https://community.datastax.com/questions/4477/. Note that you won't be able to clone the commitlogs if the destination cluster is not identical to the source cluster because the partition keys in the commitlog segments won't necessarily match the token(s) owned by the node. Cheers!

Comment: Fair enough. You are right. We are actually just cloning rather than restoring. For non-identical cluster, we are essentially doing what you listed in the datastax. However, I noticed you dont use nodetool repair. is there a reason for that? As well why do you pass sstableloader two ips for instance rather than one, the current node you are connected to? As well, it doesn't appear we have duplicate data in the tables, but rather, the space used (live and total) from nodetool cfstats per table appear to be double in size than what was reported on the original nodes.

Comment: the following command was used to retrieve live and total values per table

nodetool cfstats -H | awk -F ' *: *' '
  BEGIN { print "Keyspace,Table,Live,Total" }
  /^Keyspace : / { ks = $2 }
  /\tTable:/ { t = $2 }
  /\tSpace used .live/ { sp = $2 }
  /\tSpace used .total/ { print ks "," t "," sp "," $2 }
' | column -s , -t